# meaning of "." and ">" in the shell command

Tags: shell

I am faced with this command

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] ./main.js > ./bundle.js
```

I know browserify is a tool which bundles the necessary files in `main.js`
but i don't know what does the `>` do?
I just guess, it means that out put the result of

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] ./main.js
```

and put it in the file called `bundle.js`, so `bundle.js` must be an auto generated file, so i removed this file from directory and rerun the command but it did not get generated.

Moreover, I don't know what does the `.` mean in `./main.js` and `./bundle.js`?

Comment: that `.` means current working directory

Comment: FYI It's not a JavaScript command, it is a shell command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't a JavaScript command, it is a shell command.

`>` diverts the Standard Output stream to a file (instead of displaying it on the console).

`.` means "the current directory."

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are about shells, not JavaScript.

In most shells, `>` will "redirect" the output of a command to a file. For example, `echo test > /path/to/file` will write 'test' to that file, as `echo test` just prints 'test'.

The `.` refers to the current working directory, so that you don't need to fill in the entire `/path/to/file` but you can just use `./file` if you are currently in `/path/to`